# update "created by" in sharepoint using csom c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to update "created by" column in sharepoint. For this, i have to do using CSOM only as i do not have sharepoint server dll. I wrote code in this...

```
ClientContext cc = new ClientContext ("http://sharepoint...");
List list = cc.web.Lists.GetByTitle("sharepointlistname");
cc.Load(list);
ListItem item = list.GetItemById(13);//In this case, i want to update only id=13. I want to know code for all records also.

cc.Load(item);
cc.ExecuteQuery();
item("Created by") = "Dinesh";
item.Update();
```

When I run above code, am getting this error...

sharepoint list Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only

Comment: Your error message states `The field you are trying to update may be read only`. Are you sure you can update that field? Imo a field with the name 'created by' shouldn't be updated.

Comment: I was curious... [File.TimeCreated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee541850%28v%3doffice.15%29) only has a getter.

Comment: I'm not sure about read only. I want to find a way to update this field value with  some other value.

Comment: Yes i got you. What i meant is: presumably you can not, because the field is `read only`, as written in the error message you provided.

Comment: Does [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a65fbf3c-b9ce-43bd-9df8-cc2170242f5b/how-is-microsoftsharepointclientfileauthor-and-sharepoint-created-by-property-related?forum=sharepointdevelopment) help?

Answer (score 1):

The Created By field internal name is Author and it's a Person field, please update like this:

```
    ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/dev");
    List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
  //CamlQuery to filter items which created in Today  
  camlQuery.ViewXml =
       @"<View>  
    <Query> 
       <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Eq></Where> 
    </Query> 
    </View>";  
    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    ctx.Load(items);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    User theUser = ctx.Web.EnsureUser("Contoso\\Jerry");
    ctx.Load(theUser);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        item["Editor"] = theUser;
        item["Author"] = theUser;
        item.Update();
    }
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

[image]

Comment: Super :-) It worked. If I have to update for all ID's then what code I have to change

Comment: @Dinesh, I have updated the code snippet so that it will work for all items in a list and if the reply answered this question, I suggest you could Accept as answer so that it could also help others who have the same question in the forum. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to update only those records, which are not updated. Or I have to update only today's records. How to do that? Also, how do I click "Accept" as answer.

Comment: @Daniesh, you could filter the items using CAML Query condition with Created Modified Date and then update. I will update the reply to involve the CAML Query snippet. And Acccept as answer should be in my reply, you could find out Accept as answer.

Comment: Done, Please check, if you are not familiar with CAML Query, you can use the tool CAML Designer:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/caml-designer-2013-for-sharepoint/